# RS507 ring scanner bluetooth pairing with TC55 and read barcode using Native Android Approach

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, android-bluetooth, motorola

I need to read barcode using RS507 Ring scanner and display the results on my application present on Motorola TC55 with Bluetooth connection establishment. I'm able to pair RS507 Ring scanner to TC55 via Bluetooth connection and read barcode using EMDK library. But there is limitation that I cannot use this approach for Android Jellybean devices. So I need to use Native Android API's for RS507 Ring scanner Bluetooth connection with Motorola TC55 device and scan barcodes from Ring scanner. I'm trying to search a lot on internet for any such alternative approach or functionality, but no luck. Can somebody please help me on this? Kindly reply.

Answer (score 0):

As explained on TC55 User Manual, available on Zebra Technologies[1] [support website](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/mobile-computers/handheld/tc55.html), you need to put the RS507 in HID mode to be able to use it with Zebra's TC55.

BTW TC55 can be upgraded to KitKat, so that is probably the best option.

[1] Zebra Technologies acquired the enterprise business of Motorola Solutions in 2014.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please help on following queries : 1] With using Jellybean OS, is it required to connect ring scanner in HID mode only? 2]  I'm using Scanner.DataListener Interface In EMDK approach. In similar way can you provide any related documentation which guide scanner callback methods of native Bluetooth connectivity approach.